# To prove using the mean value theorem.

Tags: integration

**Task:**

Let $f(x)$ does not increase on $[1;+\infty]$ and $f\left(n\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ when $n∈N$.

To prove:
$\lim _n\int _n^{n^2}f\left(x\right)-ln\left(x\right)dx=+\infty \:$

Please, help me with this problem. I can't even find examples on this topic.

Comment: Can you compute $\int_n^{n^2} \ln(x) \, dx$? Can you show that $\int_n^{n^2} f(x) dx$ is at least as large? That would be a start.

Comment: $\int _n^{n^2}\:\:ln\left(x\right)dx\:=x\ln \:\left(x\right)-x=n^2\cdot ln\left(n^2\right)-n^2-\left(n\cdot ln\left(n\right)-n\right)=-n^2+2n^2\ln \:\left(n\right)-n\ln \:\left(n\right)+n$

Comment: @HansEngler,  

 what's next?

Comment: Actually the statemnt is wrong in this form since $\int_n^{n^2}f(x) dx \le \int_n^{n^2}f(1) dx = (n^2-n)$, which is less than the integral involving the $\log$.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. How to solve this example?

Comment: @andre1 - please check if you copied the problem correctly. As stated it contains an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are asked to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_n^{n^2}\left(f(x)-\log x\right)\,dx \tag 1$$

where $f$ is bounded above by $1/\sqrt{x}$.  The log function can be integrated in closed form, the result of which is

$$\int_n^{n^2}\log x=2n^2\log n-n^2-n\log n+n\tag 2$$

For the integral of $f$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_n^{n^2} f(x)\,dx&<\int_n^{n^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\\\\
&=2n-2\sqrt{n}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Using $(2)$ and $(3)$ we find that

$$\int_n^{n^2}\left(f(x)-\log x\right)\,dx<\left(2n-2\sqrt{n}\right)-\left(2n^2\log n-n^2-n\log n+n\right)$$

which clearly goes to $-\infty$ as $n\to \infty$

---

We could have used the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals to arrive at the same result.  There, we would have written

$$\int_n^{n^2}f(x)\,dx=f(\xi)(n^2-n)$$

for $n<\xi<n^2$.  But we know that $f$ is bounded above by the square root.  Therefore, we have

$$\int_n^{n^2}f(x)\,dx=f(\xi)(n^2-n)\le\frac{n^2-n}{\sqrt{n}} \tag 4$$

Using $(4)$, we have

$$\int_n^{n^2}\left(f(x)-\log x\right)\,dx<\left(\frac{n^2-n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\left(2n^2\log n-n^2-n\log n+n\right)$$

which also clearly approaches $-\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: and what can I do with this?)

Comment: @andre What term grows faster; $2n^2\log n$ or $2n$, as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Why the down vote on a HINT?

Comment: because it is not the answer((

Comment: That okay, okay.. I Just wait that someone will help me in this matter.

Comment: @andre I am happy to help.  We have two terms.  The integral of $f$ and the integral of $\log x$.  We can find an exact expression for the integral of the log, but we are not given $f$. We are given, however, some information about $f$.  We know that it is bounded above by $1/\sqrt{x}$.  Thus, we can find an upper bound for its integral.  Then, when we take this upper bound and subtract the integral of the log, we see the limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: and you could write it in more detail in the response? 
as the algorithm of actions.

Comment: @andre Sure. Give me some time, ok?

Comment: okay!!! ;))))))

Comment: @andre1 You're welcome!  My pleasure.  I added a note that makes use of the Mean Value Theorem so that it directly answers the question.